# eway rapid not working on magento multishipping checkout

Tags: checkout, payment, multishipping

when i am trying to checkout with multishipping checkout magento with eway rapid it is giving error "Please enter a valid credit card number"

**Update :**

I investigated and found that problem is here in the code...

```
`$payment = $this->getRequest()->getPost('payment');` 

$payment['cc_number']
```

....in eway payment form there is no field for cc_number and ccid. It encrypted field by this

```
<input type="text" id="ewayrapid_notsaved_cc_number" data-eway-encrypt-name="payment[cc_number]" title="Credit Card Number" class="input-text validate-cc-number validate-cc-type-auto" value="" pattern="\d*" autocomplete="off">`
```

Comment: Can I suggest trying some basic debugging first and then come here with the results you obtain. It will be much easier for others to help in that case. This is what people expect in a question on SE, some research from your part first.

Comment: thanks.i investigated and found that problem is here in the code...  $payment = $this->getRequest()->getPost('payment'); $payment['cc_number']....in eway payment form there is no field for cc_number and ccid...it encrypted field by this ....<input type="text" id="ewayrapid_notsaved_cc_number" data-eway-encrypt-name="payment[cc_number]" title="Credit Card Number" class="input-text validate-cc-number validate-cc-type-auto" value="" pattern="\d*" autocomplete="off">...please tell how to solve this issue